# Question regarding g.c.d of two polynomials

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, euclidean-domain

Let $f,g \in C[x,y]$ be two non-constant polynomials with no common factor. I want to prove that in the  Euclidean domain $C(x)[y]$ the g.c.d of $f$ and $g$ is in $C(x)$ and it looks like I'm missing something easy while proving it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $C$? The field of complex numbers?

Comment: @Arthur yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about $\mathbb{C}(x)$. If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials in the Euclidean domain $\mathbb{K}[y]$ and their gcd is *not* in $\mathbb{K}$ then the gcd is a non-trivial common factor. That holds just as well in the particular case that $\mathbb{K}$ is itself a polynomial ring.